# Custom Action argparse Python

Tags: python, action

I would like to use the same custom action for 2 different arguments:

```
class TestAction(Action):

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        car, color, state, code = values
        namespace.car = car
        namespace.color = color
        namespace.state = state
        namespace.code = code
```

When I am defining the arguments, I would like to define them as follows:

```
    parser.add_argument('--vehicle', nargs="2", action=TestAction, metavar=('car', 'color'), required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--country', nargs="2", type=tuple(str, int), action=TestAction,metavar=('state', 'code'), required=True)
```

If I am using the custom action as it is written, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```

I've been trying to define some dummy '_' and fill the empty values with "_" when unpacking, but it didn't worked.
The second issue is that I would like to force the code to be integer and the syntax `tuple(str, int)` is not correct.
Any ideas how can I correct these 2 issues?
Thanks.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959101/python-argparse-how-to-have-nargs-2-with-type-str-and-type-int

Comment: `type` cannot check more than one argument. You'll have to do the type checking inside `TestAction.__call__`. `type` has to be something with type `Callable[[str], a]` for some return type `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier way is to use something like this (without `argparse.Action`):

```py
import argparse


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('car', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('color', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('state', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('code', type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
```

**The output:**

```py
py .\test.py acar acolor acountry 1
>>> Namespace(car='acar', code=1, color='acolor', state='acountry')
```